# How to passing whole select element to a controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code which worked with me to pass whole select element:

1. **Jquery**:

   ```
    $(".btn").click(function () {
         var values = $('#id_cat option');
         var optionsData = $.map(values, function (option) {
              return option.text;
              });
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Products/Test03",
               datatype: "text",
               data: JSON.stringify(optionsData), //pass this variable to post request as 'options'
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (data) {
               //alert('Success'); //.html(data);
               },
               error: function () {
                   alert('ERROR'); //$("#testarea").html("ERROR");
                }
            });
       });
   ```

   2. **Controller**:

      ```
      public string Test03(IEnumerable<string> str1)
              {
                  // call with two parameters and return them back
                  list = str1;

                  return list.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
              }
      ```

Now I want to append the selected text in the select element and pass it along with the whole select elements. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the point of this? What are you trying to achieve by passing the exact same collection back the controller that the controller sent to the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I passed the whole items I don't know which one is selected in the above code. If you can tell me how it would be great, if not, I have to pass the selected value then.

Comment: Your controller should be (say) `public ActionResult Test03(string selectedItem)` and the ajax - `data: { selectedItem: $('#id_cat option').val() },` and remove the `contentType` option. That will pass the selected value of the dropdownlist to your method. You should not be passing back all options.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but I need the whole items as well. Those items are obtained from user input and can be changed.

Comment: That does not really make sense. If a user is dynamically adding options to a `<select>` element, then those should be saved as each one is added.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you answer my question to Barmar bellow?

Comment: To use that, you must include the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option, and then the controller method will be `public ActionResult Test03(IEnumerable<string> options, string selected)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am getting the value of options correctly but I don't know why I am getting empty string for selected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What does `var sel = $("#id_cat_option option:selected").text();` return? Is it valid? Start by just hard coding a value instead to test e.g. `selected: 'xxx'`

Comment: I think it is valid, it returned the string xxx when i swap it with your suggestion

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got it, my select id is id_cat not id_cat_option as Barmar spelled it. But I still get strange string. For example instead of I get "Aymen", I get "\n           Aymen\n"!!!!!!

Comment: It seems like you have some NewLine characters in your options. If you can't work it out, then ask a new question with the relevant information showing how your generating the options in the `<select>` element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke will give it a go and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
        data: JSON.stringify({
            options: optionsData,
            selected: $("#id_cat_option option:selected").text()
        }), //pass this variable to post request as 'options'
```

This will send a JSON object instead of an array as in your code. Use the `.option` element to get the list of all options, and `.selected` to get the text of the selected one.

And then change the controller method to

```
public ActionResult Test03(IEnumerable<string> options, string selected)
```

Comment: How should my controller look like in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know asp.net, so I don't know how to access objects with it.